# Definition and properties of $W^{-1,k}_{loc}(\Omega)$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, compactness, sobolev-spaces

I have a basic understanding of the Sobolev spaces. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $k=1,2,3... .$ I understand that $W^{-1,k}(\Omega)$ is defined as the dual of $W_0^{1,k'}(\Omega)$ where $k'$ is the conjugate exponent of $k.$ In other words, $W^{-1,k}(\Omega)$ is a normed linear space which consists of all the functionals $f :W_0^{1,k'}(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ equipped with operator norm defined by $||f||_{W^{-1,k}(\Omega)}= \sup\limits_{||\phi||_{W^{1,k'}(\Omega)}=1}|f(\phi)|.$ I recently came across the space $W^{-1,k}_{loc}(\Omega).$

**I would like to understand the followings:**

**1. Is there a norm (or atleast a metric) on $W^{1,k}_{loc}(\Omega)$?**

**2. What is the definition of $W^{-1,k}_{loc}(\Omega)$? How to interpret these spaces?** (In view of (1) is it the dual of $W^{1,k}_{loc}(\Omega)$ under the norm/metric )

**3. What do we mean by compact sets and bounded sets in $W^{-1,k}_{loc}(\Omega)$?**

Answer (score 1):

I would say that all that you wrote for $W^{1,k}(\Omega)$ can be easily seen to be true for $W^{1,k}_{loc}(\Omega)$, where for $W^{1,k}_{loc}(\Omega)$ we mean all the functions in $W^{1,k}(K)$ for any compact set $K \subset \Omega$.

Side remark: a nice (not unique) characterization of an element is its dual is the following. Embed $W^{1,p}$ in $L^p\times (L^p)^n$ and using Hahn-Banach (for the extension) and use then Riesz' representation theorem (for in $L^p$).

Comment: Thanks you @Giorgio Zorzi detto Giorgione, but I am not convinced with your answer. For simplicity, let us consider the $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ space. Clearly, any constant function is an element of  $L^1_{loc}.$ The usual $L^p$ norm can be defined on compact set but not on $\mathbb{R}.$ My question is not about the space $W^{1,k}_{loc}$ (This space is well defined i.e. all those functions whose restriction on any compact set $K$ belongs to $W^{1,k}(K)$). My concern is about the norm (or atleast metric) topology on it.

Comment: I think u got confused..by definition, norm on a vector space X is a function from X to \mathbb{R} which satisfies certain properties (see any functional anlysis book for details). My question is what is that function if X=W^{1,p}_{loc}. If there is no loc the definition of this norm function is well-know. When we consider the loc spaces there seems to be an ambiguity in defining the norm.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies, I misundestood. Let me write something about $L^{p}_{loc}$. There is no norm that induces the standard topology: no norm st $||f_n||\to0$ if and only if $\int_K|f_n|^p\to0$ for every compact $K$. But, $L^p_{loc}$ _is_ metrizable, assuming the underlying space $X$ has an "exhaustion" by compact sets. Define $$d(f,g)=\sum 2^{-n}\frac{(\int_{K_n}|f-g|^p)^{1/p}}{1+(\int_{K_n}|f-g|^p)^{1/p}}$$and then $d(f_n,0)\to0$ if and only if $\int_K|f|^p\to0$ for every compact $K$. I guess something similar can be said about the sobolev space.